# Why only minor change to function design radically changes result of criterion benchmark?

Tags: haskell, benchmarking, haskell-criterion

I have two source files which are doing roughly the same. The only difference is that in the first case function is passed as a parameter and in the second one - value.

First case:

```
module Main where

import Data.Vector.Unboxed as UB
import qualified Data.Vector as V

import Criterion.Main

regularVectorGenerator :: (Int -> t) -> V.Vector t
regularVectorGenerator = V.generate 99999

unboxedVectorGenerator :: Unbox t => (Int -> t) -> UB.Vector t
unboxedVectorGenerator = UB.generate 99999

main :: IO ()
main = defaultMain
    [
        bench "boxed"   $ whnf regularVectorGenerator (+2137)
      , bench "unboxed" $ whnf unboxedVectorGenerator (+2137)
    ]
```

Second case:

```
module Main where

import Data.Vector.Unboxed as UB
import qualified Data.Vector as V

import Criterion.Main

regularVectorGenerator :: Int -> V.Vector Int
regularVectorGenerator = flip V.generate (+2137)

unboxedVectorGenerator :: Int -> UB.Vector Int
unboxedVectorGenerator = flip UB.generate (+2137)

main :: IO ()
main = defaultMain
    [
        bench "boxed"   $ whnf regularVectorGenerator 99999
      , bench "unboxed" $ whnf unboxedVectorGenerator 99999
    ]
```

What I noticed that during benchamrking size of vector the unboxed is, as expected, always smaller yet size of both vectors vary drasticlly. Here is output of

first case:

```
 benchmarking boxed
 time                 7.626 ms   (7.515 ms .. 7.738 ms)
                     0.999 R²   (0.998 R² .. 0.999 R²)
 mean                 7.532 ms   (7.472 ms .. 7.583 ms)
 std dev              164.3 μs   (133.8 μs .. 201.3 μs)
 allocated:           1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
   iters              **1.680e7**    (1.680e7 .. 1.680e7)
   y                  2357.390   (1556.690 .. 3422.724)

 benchmarking unboxed
 time                 889.1 μs   (878.9 μs .. 901.8 μs)
                     0.998 R²   (0.995 R² .. 0.999 R²)
 mean                 868.6 μs   (858.6 μs .. 882.6 μs)
 std dev              39.05 μs   (28.30 μs .. 57.02 μs)
 allocated:           1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
   iters              **4000009.003** (4000003.843 .. 4000014.143)
   y                  2507.089   (2025.196 .. 3035.962)
 variance introduced by outliers: 36% (moderately inflated)
```

and the second case:

```
 benchmarking boxed
 time                 1.366 ms   (1.357 ms .. 1.379 ms)
                     0.999 R²   (0.998 R² .. 1.000 R²)
 mean                 1.350 ms   (1.343 ms .. 1.361 ms)
 std dev              29.96 μs   (21.74 μs .. 43.56 μs)
 allocated:           1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
   iters              **2400818.350** (2400810.284 .. 2400826.685)
  y                  2423.216   (1910.901 .. 3008.024)
 variance introduced by outliers: 12% (moderately inflated)

 benchmarking unboxed
 time                 61.30 μs   (61.24 μs .. 61.37 μs)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
 mean                 61.29 μs   (61.25 μs .. 61.33 μs)
 std dev              122.1 ns   (91.64 ns .. 173.9 ns)
 allocated:           1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
   iters              **800040.029** (800039.745 .. 800040.354)
   y                  2553.830   (2264.684 .. 2865.637)
```

Benchameked size of vector decreased by order of magnitude just by de-parametrizing function. Can someone explain me why?

I compiled both exaples with those flags:

> -O2 -rtsopts

and launched with

> --regress allocated:iters +RTS -T

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that if the generating function is already known in the benchmarked function, the generator is inlined and the involved `Int`-s are unboxed as well. If the generating function is the benchmark *parameter*, it cannot be inlined.

From the benchmarking perspective the second version is the correct one, since in normal usage we want the generating function to be inlined.